# SKOS - Simple Knowledge Organization System Namespace Document

Tags: xml, rdf

Is there any working **SKOS** (Simple Knowledge Organization System Namespace Document ) code type?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean something on the lines of .rdf file has MIME type application/rdf+xml then as yet SKOS is just one possible vocab and if you mean like scripts within document pages can be either js or vbscript, etc. then there's RDFa vocab attribute allowing semantic meta-content to benefit accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to the file types code then yes. It is mentioned in an authority table of Metadata Registry of EU Publication Office. 
[Check the filetypes table](http://publications.europa.eu/mdr/resource/authority/file-type/html/filetypes-eng.html) there is SKOS_XML code.